# Translating python sqlalchemy queries into SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For an assignment I’m working with a collection of postgreSQL databases that involve a school district. I’m trying to populate the new field `student_gpas` which is an array that stores unique student gpa’s. I have done this in python with sqlalchemy with the following code:

```
schools = db.session.query(School).filter(school.is_selected == true).all()
For sch in schools:
  grades = db.session.query(Grade).filter(grade.school_id == sch.id).all()
  For gr in grades:
    classes = db.session.query(Class).filter(class.grade_id == grades.id).all()
    For cl in classes:
      students = db.session.query(Student).filter(student.class_id == cl.id).all()
      For st in students:
    If st.gpa not in gr.student_gpas:
      gr.student_gpas.append(st.gpa)
```

What would this look like if I wanted to take this code snippet and convert it into one long and incredibly complex SQL statement

Comment: This will not be an incredibly complex sql query, just a bog standard one involving 4 tables, joins, and a where clause, plus some slightly tricker work to join up the values into a delimited list. Please post the database schema for these and some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

To see what’s being generated, just create the engine with echo=True flag.

I took the following from sqlalchemy site[1]:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
```

> The echo flag is a shortcut to setting up SQLAlchemy logging, which is accomplished via Python’s standard logging module. With it enabled, we’ll see all the generated SQL produced.

[1] https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#connecting